# how to fix read-only file system error python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a python script that runs the command line for turning a file into a .zip using python3 on my Mac.

However, whenever I run: `os.system('zip -er file.zip /Users/mymac/Desktop/file.py')` in python3, I get the error:

> ```
> zip I/O error: Read-only file system
> zip error: Could not create output file (file.zip)
> ```

I have tried disabling SIP on my Mac, as well as trying to use subprocess but I get the same message every time. I am really unsure why this happens... Is anyone able to help out?

Comment: This is not a question about python at all. What your python code does is the same as typing `zip -er file.zip /Users/mymac/Desktop/file.py` directly in the console.

Comment: So why does it raise that error? @zvone

Comment: Because you don't have write permission in the target directory, I guess. It is about your computer, not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

i will suggest 3 steps !
first run :

```
fsck -n -f
```

then reboot !

make sure to run the python file as root

```
import os
try:

    os.system('zip mag.zip mag.ppk')
    print ('success')
 except:
    print ('problem')
```

[screnshoot for my test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQb9c.png)

Comment: When I run `fsck -n -f` on my Mac terminal, I get this: `warning: option -f is not implemented, ignoring.` `error: container /dev/rdisk2 is mounted with write access; please re-run with -l.` @MoetazBrayek

Comment: u should open ur terminal as root !